# Explain {target = document.body} = {} in this function parameter

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

Can someone help me understand what is going on with `{target = document.body} = {}` the the function below?

It seems like it's passing an object as the parameter with a default of an empty object? But `target = document.body` doesn't seem like valid object syntax.

```
const replaceOnDocument = (pattern, string, {target = document.body} = {}) => {

  // Handle `string` — see the last section
  [
    target,
    ...target.querySelectorAll("*:not(script):not(noscript):not(style)")
  ].forEach(({childNodes: [...nodes]}) => nodes
    .filter(({nodeType}) => nodeType === document.TEXT_NODE)
    .forEach((textNode) => textNode.textContent = textNode.textContent.replace(pattern, string)));
};
```

Comment: It's perfectly valid, see [Object.destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a function's parameter list, `{target = document.body} = {}` means:

- The `{target}` part of it is *parameter destructuring*. It means "take the `target` property of the object provided as an argument and put it in the parameter `target`." This is called a *destructured parameter*.
- The `= document.body` part is a *destructuring default value*. It means that if there is no `target` property on the object (or its value is `undefined`), `target` should get the value `document.body`.
- The `= {}` after the closing `}` of the destructuring is a *parameter default value*. It means that if there is no argument at all for that parameter (or the argument is `undefined`), use `{}` as a default value for the parameter. After which, the destructuring is applied to that parameter default value. (More on this in the example below, it can be a bit confusing.)

The result is that `target` will either be the `target` property of the object provided as the argument (if provided and not `undefined`), or `document.body`.

For example, if you called `replaceOnDocument` with no third argument at all, that would trigger the default parameter value (`{}`); and then the destructuring would see no `target` property on it, so the destructuring default value (`document.body`) would be used.

Here's an example:

```js
function example({target = "a"} = {}) {
    console.log(`target = ${target}`);
}

// Calling with no argument at all triggers the default parameter
// value (`{}`), which in turn triggers the default destructuring
// value since `{}` doesn't have `target`.
example(); // "target = a"

// Calling with an object that doesn't have `target` just triggers the
// default destructuring value
example({randomProperty: 42}); // "target = a"

// But calling with an object that has `target`, the `target` from
// the object gets picked up
example({target: "b"}); // "target = b"

// Let's see a different value for the default parameter value:
function example2({target = "1"} = {target: "2"}) {
    console.log(`target = ${target}`);
}

// Calling with no argument at all triggers the default parameter
// value (`{}`), which in turn triggers the default destructuring
// value since `{}` doesn't have `target`.
example2(); // "target = 2"

// Calling with an object that doesn't have `target` just triggers the
// default destructuring value
example2({randomProperty: 42}); // "target = 1"

// Calling with an object that has `target`, the `target` from
// the object gets picked up
example2({target: "3"}); // "target = 3"
```

Comment: I figured there was enough going on it was worth going ahead and explaining it, but if there's a good original to point to, please don't hesitate to ping me and I'll remove this if it's redundant. I found a couple that just explain the basic destructuring, but not the whole thing.

Comment: @ jorkai - FWIW, I go into parameter defaults (Chapter 3) and destructuring (Chapter 7) -- including defaults -- in detail in my recent book, *JavaScript: The New Toys*, including this situation where they interact and it can get confusing. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the exhaustive and well documented answer, it helped a lot!